# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Student\Model\Student::getInputFilter() in D:\

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidQueryException
File:
D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement.php:245
Message:
Statement could not be executed
Stack trace:
#0 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(233): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement->execute()
#1 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(208): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#2 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(195): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#3 D:\wamp\www\album\module\Student\src\Student\Model\StudentTable.php(16): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#4 D:\wamp\www\album\module\Student\src\Student\Controller\StudentController.php(23): Student\Model\StudentTable->fetchAll()
#5 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Student\Controller\StudentController->indexAction()
#6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#9 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#11 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#14 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 D:\wamp\www\album\public\index.php(23): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#16 {main}
Previous exceptions:
PDOException
File:
D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement.php:240
Message:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'zf2tutorial.student' doesn't exist
Stack trace:
#0 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement.php(240): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(233): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement->execute()
#2 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(208): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#3 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(195): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#4 D:\wamp\www\album\module\Student\src\Student\Model\StudentTable.php(16): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#5 D:\wamp\www\album\module\Student\src\Student\Controller\StudentController.php(23): Student\Model\StudentTable->fetchAll()
#6 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Student\Controller\StudentController->indexAction()
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#12 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 D:\wamp\www\album\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 D:\wamp\www\album\public\index.php(23): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#17 {main}
© 2005 - 2013 by Zend Technologies Ltd. All rights reserved.
```

Please help me with the above error in zend framework 2.
this is giving some database error. I am using mysql db and checked the same with Album example given by Zend framework 2 and it works fine.

Comment: Is `student` table exist in `zf2tutorial` database? The error says its not.

Answer (score 2):

The "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found" error is thrown when the table from you are selecting doesn't exists. Check if a a table called student exists in the schema zf2tutorial.

If you don't want to query this table, you must change your config and the model and table classes.